# Is there a way to create a custom view for Google Store View Locator

Tags: 7, google-maps

I'm planning on using [Google Store Locator](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_store_locator) module for a custom content (lets call it datacenter) I'm creating, however I'd like to use the existing functionality plus  allow the users to filter through other properties of the datacenter?